# VS Code ctrl+click navigate to npm linked package source code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, npm

I have the following repo structure open in vscode:

```
D webapp
    D src
        F index.ts
    F package.json
D packages
    D validation
        D src
            F validation.ts
        F package.json
```

`webapp` is an node project which references the `validation` project (`cd webapp && npm install ../packages/validation`).

Let's say the `packages/validation/src/validation.ts` file looks like this:

```
export function validate(schema: Schema, object: any): ValidationError[] {
    // validation logic...
}
```

and in `webapp/src/index.ts` I call this `validate` function:

```
import { validate } from 'validation'; // assume validation package has correctly exported the validate function

const errors = validate(schema, object);
```

When I ctrl+click the validate function here, it navigates to the linked `node_modules/validation/dist/validation.d.ts` file. Is there a way to hint to vscode that the actual source directory is present in the folder so it can navigate to the actual `packages/validation/src/validation.ts` instead?

Comment: did you find any workaround? i am facing same.. any help would be appreciated.